# Switch village pop up not appearing

Tags: clash-of-clans

I signed into my buddies gamecenter and loaded his village. When I tried to sign back into mine it didn't give me the option to load my village?

Comment: If it still does not work. Can you log out Game-Center, restart your device and log in. See if that works..

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been popping up all over the forums. Supercell must've put a stop to account switching (something against the rule that a lot of players including me and you have been doing). If you are still stuck on his account there is only one fix:

1. Back up your device (if it's an Apple device, back up on iTunes)
2. Factory reset your device (clear everything off of it)
3. Load your back up onto your device (this will replace other data that you had)
4. Log back into your clash of clans account

Also, keep in mind that from now on you should not be switching accounts back and forth as you will hit this problem again. Have a nice day, I hope I was able to help.

EDIT: Whatever was happening before seemed to have stopped. Switching accounts should be working again.